# Resizing book cover according to display size (express + react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, user-interface

I'm working on a website where users can read book. In this, homepage showcase multiple books but I want this page to change the size of book cover depending upon display size and not crop them.

I'm also using mui library for creating ui elements.

Home.js

```
import { ImageList, ImageListItem, ImageListItemBar, 
    Typography, Link, Grid, Divider } from '@mui/material'
import {  useContext } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import { PageLayout, Context } from '../Components/PageLayout'

function Feed({ catg, catgTitle, routeName = "" }) {
    const navg = useNavigate();
    const bookCatg = useContext(Context)[0][catg];

    return (
        <>
            <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant="h6">{catgTitle}</Typography>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                    <Link
                        href={`/book/${routeName}`}
                        variant="body1"
                        underline="none"
                        component="button"
                    >
                        More..
                    </Link>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Divider />

            <ImageList
                sx={{ pt: '10px' }}
                cols={4}
                spacing={1}
                rowHeight={250}
            >
                {bookCatg.map((book) => (
                    <ImageListItem key={book._id}>
                        <img
                            onClick={() => navg(`/book/${book._id}`)}
                            src={book.img}
                            sx={{ height: "50px" }}
                            alt='Not Found'
                            loading="lazy"
                        />
                        <ImageListItemBar
                            onClick={() => navg(`/book/${book._id}`)}
                            sx={{ width: '10vw' }}
                            title={book.title}
                            position="below"
                        />
                    </ImageListItem>
                ))}
            </ImageList>
        </>
    )
}

export default function Home(){
    var element = <>
        <Feed catgTitle={'New Arrival'}
            catg={'newArrival'} routeName={'newest'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Popular Books'}
            catg={'popRating'} routeName={'popular'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Hot Rated'}
            catg={'hotRating'} routeName={'hot'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Rank'}
            catg={'ranking'} routeName={'ranking'} />
    </>;
    
    return (
        <PageLayout 
            url="/book"
            gridElem={element} 
            failureMsg="Error"
        />
    )
}
```

PageLayout.jsx

```
import { Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

import Navbar from './Navbar'
import AppFormNav from './AppFormNav'
import Loading from './Loading'

export const Context = createContext({});

export function PageLayout({ url, nav='normal', elem, gridElem, failureMsg }){
    const NavType = {
        'normal': <Navbar />,
        'form': <AppFormNav />
    };

    const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

    const fetchData = async() => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then((resp) => {
                if(resp.status === 200)
                    setInfo({status: 200, data: resp.data.data});
                else if(resp.status === 204) 
                    setInfo({ status: 204, data: resp.message });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setInfo({ status: 400, data: err.response.data.data })
                // console.log("Bad Request", err.resp.status);
            })
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    var gridElement = <Loading />, element, message;
    if(info.status === 200){
        gridElement = gridElem;
        element = elem;
    }
    else if (info.status === 204){
        gridElement=<></>;
        message = failureMsg ? failureMsg : info.data;
    }

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={info?.data}>
            <Grid container sx={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Grid item> { NavType[nav] } </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12}> { element } </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <Typography sx={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}> {message} </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={ 10 }> { gridElement } </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

[current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOAg0.png)

As you can see the bookcover of different size take up space of other book cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home.jsx

```
import { ImageList, ImageListItem, ImageListItemBar, 
    Typography, Link, Grid, Divider } from '@mui/material'
import {  useContext } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

import { PageLayout, Context } from '../Components/PageLayout'

function Feed({ catg, catgTitle, routeName = "" }) {
    const navg = useNavigate();
    const bookCatg = useContext(Context)[0][catg];

    return (
        <>
            <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant="h6">{catgTitle}</Typography>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                    <Link
                        href={`/book/${routeName}`}
                        variant="body1"
                        underline="none"
                        component="button"
                    >
                        More..
                    </Link>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Divider />

            <ImageList
                sx={{ pt: '10px' }}
                cols={4}
                spacing={1}
                // rowHeight={250}
            >
                {bookCatg.map((book) => (
                    <ImageListItem key={book._id}>
                        <img
                            onClick={() => navg(`/book/${book._id}`)}
                            src={book.img}
                            //changed start from here
                            style={{ aspectRatio: "0.8", resize: "auto", objectFit: "scale-down" }}
                            //change end here
                            alt='Not Found'
                            loading="lazy"
                        />
                        <ImageListItemBar
                            onClick={() => navg(`/book/${book._id}`)}
                            sx={{ width: '10vw' }}
                            title={book.title}
                            position="below"
                        />
                    </ImageListItem>
                ))}
            </ImageList>
        </>
    )
}

export default function Home(){
    var element = <>
        <Feed catgTitle={'New Arrival'}
            catg={'newArrival'} routeName={'newest'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Popular Books'}
            catg={'popRating'} routeName={'popular'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Hot Rated'}
            catg={'hotRating'} routeName={'hot'} />
        <Feed catgTitle={'Rank'}
            catg={'ranking'} routeName={'ranking'} />
    </>;
    
    return (
        <PageLayout 
            url="/book"
            gridElem={element} 
            failureMsg="Error"
        />
    )
}
```

just added this style to img tag

> style={{ aspectRatio: "0.8", resize: "auto", objectFit: "scale-down"
> }}

[image: Here's the result]